# BST with linked queue output errors

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list, binary-search-tree

Having trouble assigning a new node to a list of dynamic nodes, actually I can only get the first node on there. Once duplicates are detected either I am not printing them properly(unlikely) or they are not allocating. Everything prints fine, except only the first number that was inserted into the queue displays.

```
typedef struct lineList
{
    int lineNum;
    LIST *next;
}LIST;

typedef struct nodeTag{
   char data[80];
   LIST *lines;
   struct nodeTag *left;
   struct nodeTag *right;
} NODE;
```

call to addtolist

```
    mover = (*root)->lines;
    printf("Node already in the tree!\n");
    while(mover)
        mover = mover->next;
    mover = addToList();  //allocate memory for new node
    mover->lineNum = line; //set data
```

adding to list

```
LIST *addToList()
{
    LIST *pnew;
    pnew = (LIST *) malloc(sizeof (LIST)); //memory for LIST
    if (!pnew)
    {
        printf("Fatal memory allocation error in insert!\n");
        exit(3);
    }
    pnew->next = NULL; //set next node to NULL

    return pnew;
}
```

tree output to file(i have small issues here as well with some nodes
printing twice)

```
void treeToFile(NODE *root, FILE *fp)
{
    if(root->left)
    {
      treeToFile(root->left, fp);
      fprintf(fp, "%-15s",  root->data);
      printList(root->lines, fp);
      fprintf(fp, "\n");
   }
   if(root->right)
   {
      treeToFile(root->right, fp);
      fprintf(fp, "%-15s",  root->data);
      printList(root->lines, fp);
      fprintf(fp, "\n");
   }
   return;
}
```

printing list

```
void printList(LIST *myList, FILE *fp)
{
    LIST *mover;
    mover = myList;
    while(mover) //while mover
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%5d", mover->lineNum); //line nums where string occurs
        mover = mover->next; //move to next node
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the link, look at this code:

```
while(mover)
    mover = mover->next;
mover = addToList();  //allocate memory for new node
mover->lineNum = line; //set data
```

Your while makes non-sense... you leave the while when  'mover' == NULL, what you wanna do is having the last node (the one whose next is null)

Changer your code to the following

```
// the IF below is for the case when the queue is empty, so you won't try to dereference a NULL
// in the while condition
if(mover)               
    while(mover->next)
        mover = mover->next;

if(mover) // make sure you have at least one element in the queue
{
    mover->next = addToList();  //allocate memory for new node
    mover->next->lineNum = line; //set data
}
else // if the queue is empty, then lines will return NULL and you 
       //are inserting the first element
{
    mover = addToList();
    mover->lineNum = line;
    (*root)->lines = mover; // here you are putting the new element in the first position 
                          // of your queue (It is necessary to do this because 
                          // it is currently empty!
}
```

The code above is what to do to fix your code. I have 2 suggestions depending on what your queue means.

First: Do you need ordering for this queue? The order of elements are inserted matter to you?

If yes, then a queue is what you need, but instead of going through the whole list for every insertiong, you can have a struct like this:

```
struct queue
 {
    LIST *first;
    LIST *last;
 }
```

and you will inser the new elements in last->next (the first element is different since last will be null there... you would need to make next and first point to that element)

Or, if you the order doesn't matter, just add the new element at the begining of the list

```
mover = addToList();
mover->lineNum = line;
mover->next = *(root)->lines; //supposing you are using the right side correctly in your code,  
                       // you are adding the current list as being the next of your new element

*(root)->lines = mover; //here you are saying that your list starts now at your new element
```

Comment: excellent suggestion as to how to optimize the program. I am reading in line numbers so they already read in order.